# What is Adaptation in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

In XCode Interface Builder there is a new view if you switch the Device to iPad, like this:

[image]

What is it the Adaptation good for?

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 10 on iPad you can use the split screen function, which displays two apps on your screen at the same time. You can also adjust the ratio of the two.
With these options you can simulate the changes in Interface Builder:

[image]

The following figure ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html)) shows you what size-classes will be applied to your app (based on orientation and split screen size adjustments)
[image]